# What is the difference between the extrinsics utility.batch() and utility.batchAll()?

Tags: extrinsic

I would like to batch several extrinsic calls into one transactions, but I am not sure if I should use `utility.batch()` or `utility.batchAll()`. **What is the difference?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`utility.batchAll()`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ded44948e2d5a398abcb4e342b0513cb690961bb/frame/utility/src/lib.rs#L284) does not commit if one of the calls in the batch fails.

> The whole transaction will rollback and fail if any of the calls failed.

[`utility.batch()`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ded44948e2d5a398abcb4e342b0513cb690961bb/frame/utility/src/lib.rs#L177) commits each successful call regardless if a call fails.

> If a call failed and the batch was interrupted, then the
> `BatchInterrupted` event is deposited, along with the number of
> successful calls made and the error of the failed call. If all were
> successful, then the `BatchCompleted` event is deposited.

Comment: Can you provide us a couple of scenarios where `utility.batch()` and `utility.batchAll()`  are used? I've never found myself calling them directly although I have noticed that they get triggered when I am staking.

Comment: [Here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2087/29) is a scenario where `utility.batchAll()` is used. In this case, I want to ensure the first extrinsic succeeds before the second one is called.