# How do I reset my parachain's state?

Tags: parachain, rococo-local

I am running Rococo local on my machine and my parachain stalled. I would like to reset the state of my parachain and restart my collator. **How do I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is reset the state for your parachain:

[image]

If you want to reset the state and upload new code then you can use `utility.batchAll()` and call `paras.forceSetCurrentHead()` and `paras.forceSetCurrentCode()`.

[image]

Then restart your collator(s) and you should see the `paras.head()` change.

[image]